# React state wrongly updated in nested components with CodeMirror 6 Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codemirror, codemirror-6

I have a few components nested inside a larger "controller" component.

The whole demo app is below. There's also a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fc9tgt?file=src%2FApp.js).

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CodeEditor from './CodeEditor';
import './style.css';

const PostEditor = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {value && (
        <>
          <CodeEditor value={value} onChange={value => onChange(value)} />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const Wrapper = ({ post, updatePostProperty }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Selected post: {post && post.title}</h2>
      {post && post.title && (
        <PostEditor
          value={post.title}
          onChange={value => {
            console.log('update title->', value);
            updatePostProperty(post.id, 'title', value);
          }}
        />
      )}
      {post && post.subTitle && (
        <PostEditor
          value={post.subTitle}
          onChange={value => {
            console.log('update subTitle->', value);
            updatePostProperty(post.id, 'subTitle', value);
          }}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
    { id: 1, title: 'post no 1', subTitle: 'subtitle no 1' },
    { id: 2, title: 'post no 2', subTitle: 'subtitle no 2' },
    { id: 3, title: 'post no 3', subTitle: 'subtitle no 3' }
  ]);
  const [post, setPost] = useState();

  const updatePostProperty = (id, property, value) => {
    const newPosts = [...posts];
    const index = newPosts.findIndex(post => (post.id === id));
    newPosts[index] = {
      ...newPosts[index],
      [property]: value
    };
    setPosts(newPosts);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {posts &&
          posts.length > 0 &&
          posts.map((post, index) => (
            <li
              style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
              onClick={() => {
                setPost(post);
              }}
            >
              {post.title} - {post.subTitle}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>

      <Wrapper post={post} updatePostProperty={updatePostProperty} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `App` component hosts the `updatePostProperty` that is passed on to the `Wrapper` component which uses it when the `PostEditor` component triggers `onChange` the `CodeEditor` which is a wrapper for `CodeMirror`.

The issue here is that after you click one of the posts and edit the title and then the subtitle, the title gets reverted to the initial value.

Scenario:
Click on the first post and try to edit the title. Add an `!` to the title. You'll see the post on the list gets updated.
After you edit the subtitle by adding a character to it, you'll see the title gets reverted to the previous state (without the `!`) in the `App` component.

Why is react doing this "revert" update?

[image: gif demonstrating bad react behaviour]

---

**Update**:

[New StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pu1axz?file=src%2FCodeEditor.js).

- I made a few adjustments to the script to use `useEffect` before changing the original `posts` array.
- I added a regular `input` element to see if the problem persists. It seems that the issue is fixed with regular `input`s.

However, I'd love someone's input on why does the issue still persists with the way CodeMirror is wired up.

Comment: Should `posts[index] =` be `newPosts[index] =`?

Answer (score 1):

Inside `updatePostProperty` you're updating the wrong object.

You're updating:

```
posts[index] = {
  ...newPosts[index],
  [property]: value
};
```

But you want to update `newPosts` instead, so you have to do:

```
newPosts[index] = {
  ...newPosts[index],
  [property]: value
};
```

Comment: my bad with those mistakes. I updated the code and the issue is now visible. thanks 

Comment: @adrianthedev the problem is inside `CodeEditor` because if you replace it with a textarea everything works as espected.

Comment: Yeah. I see that in the new [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pu1axz?file=src%2FCodeEditor.js). Do you have any thoughts on how to better emit the change from CodeMirror?

Answer (score 0):

1. it needs to be `newPosts` instead of `posts`
2. no need to destructuring
3. you are using 1 `=` here `newPosts.findIndex(post => (post.id = id));` there suppose to be 2 `==` like `newPosts.findIndex(post => (post.id == id));`

checkout this code

```
  const updatePostProperty = (id, property, value) => {
    const newPosts = [...posts]; 
    const index = newPosts.findIndex(post => (post.id == id)); 
    newPosts[index][property] = value
    setPosts(newPosts);
  };
```

Comment: my bad with those mistakes. I updated the code and the issue is now visible. thanks 